# IEEE 754: can casting before division cause loss of precision?

Tags: floating-point, precision, division, arbitrary-precision

Do there exist two integers `i` and `j` that both fit into an IEEE 754 double (are smaller than `DBL_MAX`), but such that `to_double(i)/to_double(j)` is not equal to `to_double(i/j)`, where this `i/j` is performed with unlimited precision?

(We can assume `to_double` is round-to-even if that matters).

My question is similar to [Invertability of IEEE 754 floating-point division](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38709206/invertability-of-ieee-754-floating-point-division), but I don't think it is equivalent, or at least I don't see how to use it to get a counter-example to my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. In a C implementation where `double` is IEEE-754 basic 64-bit binary floating-point (with 53-bit significands) and `long double` has 64-bit significands, the output of:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    long double x = 0x1p154L - 0x1p101L + 0x1p100L;
    long double y = 0x1p153L + 0x1p101L - 0x1p100L;
    long double z = x / y;
    double X = x;
    double Y = y;
    double Z = X/Y;
    printf("x = %La.\n", x);
    printf("y = %La.\n", y);
    printf("z = %La.\n", z);
    printf("X = %a.\n", X);
    printf("Y = %a.\n", Y);
    printf("Z = %a.\n", Z);
    printf("(double) z = %a.\n", (double) z);
}
```

is:

```
x = 0xf.ffffffffffffcp+150.
y = 0x8.0000000000004p+150.
z = 0xf.ffffffffffff4p-3.
X = 0x1p+154.
Y = 0x1p+153.
Z = 0x1p+1.
(double) z = 0x1.ffffffffffffep+0.
```

`x / y` is performed with `long double` precision, of course, rather than infinite precision, but it captures sufficient information to show the result with infinite precision would have the same end result—inserting `#include <math.h>` and `z = nexttowardl(z, INFINITY);` changes `(double) z` to be `0x1.fffffffffffffp+0`, but this is still not equal to `Z`.